# D3.js - Is it possible to animate between a force-directed graph and a node-link tree?

Tags: animation, d3.js, tree, force-layout

I am using the `D3.js` library and looking at the force-directed graph demo:

http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/force.html

[image]

I am also looking at the node-link tree:

http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/tree.html

[image]

What I would like to do is:

*- Start with the force-directed graph and when the user clicks on a
   node, have it animated smoothly into a tree, with the selected node
   in the center.
 - Then, when the user clicks on any empty space in the canvas, it
   should animate back to the force-directed graph.*

Has anyone done anything like this before, or have any advice as to the best approach to take?  I am new to D3.js and have no idea if this is even supported by the framework.

Comment: Upon reflection, I realized that I don't want to specifically change the force-directed graph into a tree - I want to re-position the nodes so that the selected node is centered, and its connections are arranged around it, and their connections around them, and so on.  What I think I want to do is explicitly set all of the node coordinates and link lengths and keep them fixed.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the intent here. Having "its connections are arranged around it, and their connections around them" when you're not dealing with a hierarchical structure is exactly what a force-directed layout does. Should all the nodes and links still be visible after I click?

Comment: Possibly, you could have an invisible node with fixed position in the middle; and whenever user selects a node - you add a link (with force much bigger than other forces) between it (the invisible middle) and selection. (also, whenever user selects new node - the previous link needs to be removed)

Comment: To make connections of clicked node located **around** it, you would need to add a chain of equal forces (this time, repulsive) among its 1st level children (again, significantly bigger than other forces on your graph)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need to do is stop the force and apply a transformation of the existing nodes to the x-y derived from the other layout. So your function would look like this:

```
force.stop();
d3.selectAll("g.nodes").transtion().duration(500)
    .attr("translate","transform("+newLayoutX+","+newLayoutY+")"
```

Then iterate through your nodes array and set the `x`, `y`, `px`, `py` values to reflect the new `X` and `Y`. This will set your nodes to know the current `x` and `y` position for the force layout when you run `force.start()`

You can take a look at the `plotLayout()` function in this example:

https://gist.github.com/emeeks/4588962

This does not rely on a second d3.layout, though. The problem you'll run into is that you need a hierarchical dataset for the tree layout, which requires you to transform your nodes and edges data into an array of node.children as expected in the hierarchical layouts. The way that I would do it is to duplicate the dataset and manually flatten it, but there may be a more elegant solution that I'm unaware of.