# Is there a D3 layout engine like force layout but with click event support

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, dom-events, force-layout

I want to draw a directed graph where any node can link to any other node (ie no defined hierarchy) and I was using the force layout engine but it doesn't support click event handling.  I want to be able to click on a node and have that node centered and everything else laid out around it.

Is that possible in D3?

EDIT:
According to the API documentation for d3.force.layout:

> force.on(type, listener)
>
> Registers the specified listener to receive events of the specified
>   type from the force layout. Currently, only "tick" events are
>   supported

which suggests that simply adding a click event handler will not work.

Also, a tree layout needs (as far as I know) a hierarchy and my data is more tangled.

Comment: If you're talking about [this](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/force.html) force layout, I don't see why it wouldn't be possible. Have you tried `node.on("click", handler())`?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986702/d3-js-is-it-possible-to-animate-between-a-force-directed-graph-and-a-node-link#comment15921752_8986702) looks like a similar question.

Comment: Answering click handler comment by editing the question.

Comment: I was wrong. Sorry about misleading answer.

Comment: Alm, thanks for trying to help.

Comment: The lack of click handler for layout may be misleading. I need to attach a click handler to the node or circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After puzzling away at this, I have something close to what I wanted so I'll share.

Firstly, There is no click handler for the layout engine but that is not needed for this; I wanted to click on a node and have that become fixed so I need a click handler on the node.

Secondly, there is a "fixed" property at the node level described in the d3 API for the force layout engine.

Combining these two, I can add click handler to the node that locks or unlocks the node's position.

Using the example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/1153292) I  add the following to the CSS:
`circle:hover { fill: red; }`
and change the circle definition from:

```
var circle = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("circle")
.data(force.nodes())
.enter().append("svg:circle")
.attr("r", 6)
.call(force.drag);
```

to

```
var circle = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("circle")
.data(force.nodes())
.enter().append("svg:circle")
.attr("r", 6)
.on("click", function(d){ d.fixed = 1 - d.fixed; force.start(); })
.call(force.drag);
```

and now, when I mouse-over a circle, it turns red (showing me I captured it) and then if I click, it locks it in place.  I can then repeat this on other circles and drag them to where I want.